# React Hooks Static Variables: Object Property vs useRef()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static, react-hooks

What are the advantages or disadvantages to declaring static variables in a React functional components within a `useRef()` hook vs. simply declaring them as an object property.

**useRef Approach:**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {

  const staticProp = useRef("Hello, World!");

  return (
    <div>{staticProp.current}</div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**Object Property Approach:**

```
import React from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {

  return (
    <div>{MyComponent.staticPro}</div>
  )
}

MyComponent.staticProp = "Hello, World!";

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refs are useful for [mutable values](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) bound to your component instances. They are similar to instance variables. If the variable is supposed to be static, you don't need refs. You can declare it as a property of your component function, or as a constant in the outer scope:

```
const staticProp = "Hello, World!";

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>{staticProp}</div>
  )
}
```