# What is the best way to declare static variables in React functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, react-hooks

Which is the best way to declare variables in React functional components (From now on - RFC)?  It is not duplicate to [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176036/react-hooks-static-variables-object-property-vs-useref) this one.

As for me, there are a few ways of declaring variables `

1. Declaring it with `const` inside RFC - If we pass this to the `HeavyComponent` component, so on each render, it will create a new reference, and `HeavyComponent` will render too. Not a good option.
2. Declaring with `useRef` inside RFC - The reference will be the same within subsequent renders, which is good, but on the other hand, we are using `useRef` internal method (Function call - which does some job under the hood)
3. Declaring with `const` outside of RFC (outer scope) - In this case, the reference will be again the same, as it will be taken from the closure and we don't use `useRef` method. But, in this particular case, we declare that variable in the outer scope and it is not being garbage collected and will cause memory leaks (if we use that cases very often).

I know, each case has its pros and cons. But when do we stick with a certain option?

**UPDATED**
Here is the example

```
export const UnemployedEmployeesReportPaper = React.memo((props: IProps) => {
    const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState('');
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

    const headerColumns = useRef([
        { children: 'First Name', width: 240, flexGrow: 1, sortValue: item => item.FirstName },
        { children: 'Last Name', width: 240, flexGrow: 1, sortValue: item => item.LastName },
        { children: 'Last day of employment', width: 240, flexGrow: 1, sortValue: item => moment(item.Since).format('L') },
    ]).current;

    const filterEmployee = (event: SyntheticEvent): void => {
        const { value } = event.target;
        const { payload } = props.unemployedEmployees;

        const newTableData = payload.filter((row: ISimpleEmployeeRowData): boolean =>
            (row.FirstName).toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));

        setTableData(newTableData);
        setFilterText(value);
    };

    const rows = useMemo(() => {
        return tableData.map(entry => {
            return {
                data: [
                    { children: entry.FirstName },
                    { children: entry.LastName },
                    { children: entry.Since },

                ],

                onDoubleClick: (): void => props.goToEmployees(entry.ID),
                // Empty onClick will turn the hovering of table on
                onClick: () => {}
            };
        });
    }, [tableData]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.unemployedEmployees.payload) {
            setTableData(props.unemployedEmployees.payload);
        }

        setFilterText('');
    }, [props.unemployedEmployees]);



    return (
        <VTable
           sortable
           striped
           rowHeight={36}
           headerColumns={headerColumns}
           rows={rows}
        />);
});
```

Here is used `useRef`, but I am not sure if it's better than just declaring it outside of RFC.

Comment: What kind of answer you are looking for? What are the use cases for each? As if you know the props/cons it becomes opinioned question

Comment: If you pay attention to my title and also to the bottom of the question , there I mentioned what I need . What is the best way to do it and I am sure , there are cases , that one if them is preferable

Comment: So what is the use case? Do you have any particular one and you don't know what you should do?

Comment: I have used all of them, but don't know which one is better in certain cases

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to say, show us the **certain cases**, in Stackoverflow, as you know, that's kind of question that should be asked. I can come up with cases, but they will be arbitrary. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to store variables in a functional component depends on your useCase.

In most cases you can make use of useRef hook since it returns you the same instance of the variable on each render of the function.

You can however define a variable and assign its value using useMemo hook too.

like

```
const val = useMemo(() => {
   return some calculation based value or in general a normal value
},[]) // dependency array to recalculate value
```

You must note that useRef helps you get around closure issues and comes in handy when you want to use variables that are affected by closure. For instance using a value from closure inside a setInterval function defined within useEffect with empty dependency.

On the other hand useMemo will help you prevent references change for variables no each re-render. A common useCase of this would be to provide a memoized value for ContextProvider

**UPDATE:**

For your usecase, there are two ways to define headerColumns.

- Outside of the component as a constant. Declaring it as a constantoutside of the functional component makes sense when the value is not expected to change, nor is it expected to use any value from the closure
- As a memozied value within the function

```
 const headerColumns = useMemo( () => [
        { children: 'First Name', width: 240, flexGrow: 1, sortValue: item => item.FirstName },
        { children: 'Last Name', width: 240, flexGrow: 1, sortValue: item => item.LastName },
        { children: 'Last day of employment', width: 240, flexGrow: 1, sortValue: item => moment(item.Since).format('L') },
    ], []);
```

You must note the using `useMemo` to assign value to `headerColumns` makes sense when you use value from closure.

Comment: Why use useRef, if you can declare it outside of the component and get the variable through closure? what's the difference? And when to choose one over another?

Comment: It is because if you declare it outside of the component you can't create multiple instances of the component each having a separate reference of the variable in a different parent component

Answer (score 2):

In your use-case, `headerColumns` should be in outer scope:

```
const headerColumns = [
  {
    children: "First Name",
    width: 240,
    flexGrow: 1,
    sortValue: (item) => item.FirstName,
  },
  // more
];

export const UnemployedEmployeesReportPaper = React.memo((props) => {});
```

If its a "read-only" object, it should be in the outer scope.

See [Why need useRef to contain mutable variable but not define variable outside the component function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444154/why-need-useref-to-contain-mutable-variable-but-not-define-variable-outside-the/57444430#57444430).

In your current situation, if you have N `UnemployedEmployeesReportPaper` components, you will have N `headerColumns` references, instead on outer scope all components **will share the same immutable object** (immutable because in your use case, it acts as read-only object).

Comment: I know , that variables in outer scope are global , and not being garbage collected . What about it ?

Comment: Are you sure it won't garbage collected? Did you check it? It is not a **real** global variable, it is in scope of the component's file.

Comment: Also, do you prefer N copies of the same object over all your components? So basically you claim that it is better to have N copies of the same object than one object that "doesn't" gets garbage collected

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure about garbage collecting, but your argument is good and can be a good point to choose one over another

Comment: @DennisVash So just to be sure, the variable kept outside the component will get garbage collected/destroyed just like any other variable kept inside component when component unmounts?
I want to keep a class instance variable which I need to initialize only once. Would keeping it outside be a good idea?

Comment: Yes, but for more context just ask a question